# Mocking @Log in Groovy

Tags: groovy, mockito

Given a class annotated with @Log; is it possible to mock the injected logger with Mockito for unit testing? Is this correct "Groovy-way" of doing things?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I've achieved this is to define another Logger variable within the class to be tested, non-final and with a more permissive scope. The constructor then defaults to taking the injected logger and assigning it the more permissive object. In the tests, the logger instance can be set to a mockito mocked object which is then assigned to the more permissive object.

Not as perfect as allowing for the mocking of injected objects; but functional.

Answer (score 0):

We've been having some issues while using Mockito with Groovy, as it is described [here](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/72). Perhaps, you might want to use another mocking framework with Groovy support, such as [GMock](https://code.google.com/p/gmock/).

For more info you can check also this [link](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Using+Testing+Frameworks+with+Groovy).